Necklace conjectures involving $f(n) =$ the number of $n-$bead necklaces with $2$ colors. (A000031)
consider $f(n)$ for $n>0$ :
$f(n) =$ the number of $n-$bead necklaces with $2$ colors when turning over is not allowed.
So we get
$$f(1) = 2$$
(a binary bit or bead)
$$f(2) = 3$$
($11$,$00$ or $01 = 10$ so $3$ ways)
$$f(3) = 4$$
$$f(4) = 6$$
We get the list
$$2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 14, 20, 36, 60, 108, 188, 352, 632, 1182, 2192, ...$$
basically equal to
https://oeis.org/A000031
Conjecture $C$ :
for all $n>0$ :
$$f(n) < 2^{L n} + n$$
Where $L$ satisfies $L + \exp(L) = 2$
So $L = 2 - W(e^2)$
($L$ is about $0.4428$)
where $W(x)$ is the LambertW function. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function )
Conjecture $D$ :
$$ \lim \frac{\ln(f(n))}{\ln(2) n} = L^*$$
for some constant $L^*$.
Can we prove those ?
What is the value of $L^*$ ??
Do we have $L^* = L $ ?
It seems $L^*$ is at most $L$.
Another candidate for $L^*$ is $V$
$$ L^* =^? V = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + 2^x + 3^x} $$
Where $V$ seems like a lower bound for $L^*$.
($V$ is about $0.4316$ )
Im not sure how Pólya enumeration theorem and the alike can help here if at all.
Same for the Necklace polynomials.
I am not sure what are the open problems or solved ones regarding this.
That weird integral occured in the comments here today :
Integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{1+2^x+3^x}$
where user https://math.stackexchange.com/users/905886/%d0%a2yma-gaidash
considered changing the domain of integration.
I recognized that value from the numerical experiments I did recently with A000031, although none of that is formal or anything.
I was unable to find anything in the books that seemed like helpful to me, although I am new to this.

Added numerical values

Conjecture C is false. It's a standard exercise using Burnside's lemma to show that
$$f(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} \varphi(d) 2^{\frac{n}{d}}$$
which gives
$$f(n) \ge \frac{2^n}{n}.$$
So no inequality of the form $f(n) < 2^{Ln} + n$ can hold for any $L < 1$. I have no idea where your value of $L$ comes from numerically; with $L = 0.4428$ your conjecture already fails for $n = 6$.
Conjecture D is true with $L^{\ast} = 1$, since we also have an asymptotically matching upper bound $f(n) \le 2^n$, which gives
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln f(n)}{n \ln 2} = 1.$$
I have no idea what $V$ has to do with this sequence.

hmm logarithmic scatterplot of A000031 gives log(A000031(1000)) around 300.
So I assumed the log was base $e$. But I guess that assumption was wrong and it is base $10$ because then it fits since then $1/\ln(10) = 0.434..$ what is close to my values of $L$ ...

Possibly worth mentioning that $\frac{2^n}n\le f(n)\le2^n$ is clear without the exact Burnside's Lemma calculation, as $2^n$ counts each necklace between $1$ and $n$ times.
